# Pod shell - modifying the already declared ENV variables

Tags: bash, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubectl

Context/why am I looking for that strange way:

> the pod (pods) where I'm trying to inject the envs are spawned by a job and there are hundreds of them. There is also a configmap in k8s which holds all the envs. I'm doing this to avoid manually declaring hundreds of pods with different env vars

I have a pod in k8s with defined env vars in the manifest:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    name: something
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", "sleep 60 && source ~/.bashrc && env | grep FOO"]
    env:
    - name: FOO
      value: bar
    - name: FOO2
      value: bar2
```

I also run another pod with kubectl and rbac set that executes:

```
kubectl  exec -i FIRST_POD_NAME -- bash -c "echo 'FOO=updated_bar' >> ~/.bashrc"
```

first pods use (sleep is to ensure the other pods has time to update the values of env vars):

```
sleep 60 && source ~/.bashrc && env | grep FOO
```

as command and it logs:

```
FOO=bar

FOO2=bar2
```

but when I manually enter the pod (bash) and run:

```
env | grep FOO
```

I see `FOO=updated_bar`

What am I missing here and how to update these envs so the pod uses them in start cmd?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use Kubernetes debugging tools to reinvent the per-container environment.  Why not directly set the `env:` to have the value you want (maybe via a ConfigMap, or maybe using a tool like Kustomize or Helm that can modify it at deploy time)?  Using `kubectl exec` this way is unreliable: it can't affect multiple replicas of a Deployment, and if a Pod is deleted and recreated by the cluster, your manual changes will be lost.

Comment: Agreed, I should have shared a wider view:
The pod (pods) where I'm trying to inject the envs are spawned by a job and there are hundreds of them. There is also a configmap in k8s which holds all the envs. I'm doing this to avoid manually declaring hundreds of pods with different env vars.

I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was unable to find a reason for this, I've made a workaround so if anyone needs to do something similar:

helping pod is just appending the values to tmp files in other pods:

```bash
kubectl  exec -i FIRST_POD_NAME -- bash -c "echo 'FOO=updated_bar' > /tmp/foo
```

and on the startup I read the value of this fire and use it as ENV:

```bash
# some sleep is needed to let the helping pod created this file
sleep n && export FOO=$(cat /tmp/foo)
```

> this is a poor, but working solution to import envs declared in configmap to hundrets of pods

Answer (score 0):

Environmental variables are set on the pod start itself. It won't need any sleep.

For more information about kubernetes environment variable: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

`why am I looking for that strange way?`

To answer this question,

1. I could see you are missing `export` key word in `kubectl  exec -i FIRST_POD_NAME -- bash -c "echo 'FOO=updated_bar' >> ~/.bashrc"`. If you are missing the export then the variable will be considered as `shell variable` and not an `environmental variable` and  this updated `FOO` variable will be ignored during `source ~/.bashrc`.
2. `~/.bashrc` file is user specific. Please compare the pod `user_name` during the `start up` and the `user_name` while executing `kubectl  exec -i FIRST_POD_NAME -- bash -c "echo 'export FOO=updated_bar' >> ~/.bashrc"`. If both the `user_name's` are different then. You will see the strange behaviour.

Comment: as mentioned in my question:
> sleep is to ensure the other pod has time to update the values of env vars

I've updated my question with an explanation of why I'm looking for these strange way

Comment: Updated the reason for why you are seeing strange behaviour?